# CDI @TransactionAttribute for bean

Tags: java, transactions, java-ee-6, cdi

I am experimenting with `CDI` on a test application. I have a `DAO` which injects a container managed `JTA` persistence context like this:

```
public class TestDAO implements Serializable {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void insertEntity(Test test) {
        entityManager.persist(test);
    }
}
```

Now I have a CDI controller bean like this:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class TestController implements Serializable {
    @Inject
    private TestDAO testDAO;

    public void finishGame() {
        testDAO.insertEntity(new Test(1, 2, 3));
    }
}
```

If I run this, I receive an error in the `DAO` when trying to insert the entity, because there is no active transaction available. So far so good. I can solve this by making the controller bean a stateful `EJB` which will wrap the `finishGame()` in a transaction.

But let assume I don't want an `EJB`. As a test I annotated the `finishGame()` with the `@TransactionAttribute` annotation and it worked(the controller bean is NOT an `EJB`). So my question is: how does it work? Does the `CDI` define `@TransactionAttribute` for plain beans? I know that `Seam Persistence Module` does this, but I am not using it. Actually I added it to the project, but I removed it after, because I received awkward exceptions.

Could anyone clear my confusion? Do really `CDI` define `@TransactionAttribute` for plain beans?

P.S. I have another sort of question. I see the tendencies is to port all `EJB` annotations to plain beans. So will `EJBs` become obsolete in the future? I mean I saw in `JIRA` that `@TransactionAttribute` will be added in the future for plain beans(the task is still not resolved). So isn't this eclipsing EJBs, sort of duplicating functionality?

Best regards,
Petar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need do define a transaction interceptor. Basically define a @Transactional annotation and intercept all methods annotated with it. In the interceptor just begin, commit or rollback the transaction. It gets more complicated when transaction propagation comes into the picture. So check if Seam doesn't have anything ready-to-use http://seamframework.org/Seam3/PersistenceModule

Comment: +1, thanks for the useful answer! But my question is why `@TransactionAttribute` worked on a plain `CDI` bean, without doing anything? I have always thought that `@TransactionAttribute` works only for `EJBs`.

Comment: yes, I think it's the case - @TransactionAttribute should not work out-of-the box

Comment: Yeah and that's the strange thing. When you have enough time, could you just make a simple `CDI` application and try if the `@TransactionAttribute` works on a plain `CDI` bean. It is driving me crazy because I know it shouldn't work on a plain bean...

Comment: I will also make again a sample application from scratch to confirm if I am missing something, which is the most probable case:)

Comment: http://www.theserverside.com/tip/Dependency-Injection-in-Java-EE-6-Part-6 this here tells what I thought - if there is seam, it can plug-in CDI and allow @TransactionAttribute to be resolved.  But not with plain CDI.

Comment: Thanks for the link, maybe the appication server has cached something. Because I added `Seam Persistence` at first to the project and then I removed it. I will try it again tonight.

Comment: This was the case. `Glassfish` has cached the libraries and descriptors, although I told `NetBeans` to clean the build. Now it throws a transaction required exception as it should be. Thanks for helping:)